# Semantic UI Multiple Select dropdown gives weird output when initialized twice

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

While trying to create a multiple select dropdown with no label, something weird happens. This is the js code used for this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectionTool').dropdown({
        useLabels: false
    });
});
```

At the end this function is called:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

What happens now, is that at first labels are used in the file. See in the gif what happens when I do this, [what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRIcr.gif). Without the second function everything works fine.

Is there a way this issue can be fixed without deleting the second function?
Version 2.2 is used of Semantic UI

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are reinitializing the dropdown, when you call the dropdown method with settings this initializes it as a dropdown it doesn't only set the settings.

---

Try using only one dropdown method:

html

```
<select name="skills" multiple="" class="ui fluid dropdown">
  <option value="">Skills</option>
  <option value="angular">Angular</option>
  <option value="css">CSS</option>
  <option value="design">Graphic Design</option>
  <option value="ember">Ember</option>
  <option value="ux">User Experience</option>
</select>
```

js

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    useLabels: false
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e1kmL68v/

Comment: Yes I know, however there are some dropdowns that are initialized at the end. Is there maybe a way to see if a dropdown already is initialized and then skip it?

Comment: Just be more specific to that dropdown and use an id instead of `.ui.dropdown`